# Flutter. How to navigate to new page without save into the stack

Tags: flutter, back-stack, flutter-navigation

How to navigate to new page without save into the stack.
For example I have two page: A and B. From page A you can open B; from B you can open A.
I'd like it so that every opening of B does not get saved into the 'history'. So, pressing back from A cannot return to B.

In android it can be implemented with the help of the intent flag. For example:

```
Intent i = new Intent(...); // my Activity B
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY); // Adds the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY flag, which keeps the new Activity from being added to the history stack.
startActivity(i);
```

Is it possible to implement this behavior on flutter, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pushReplacement](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/pushReplacement.html) to achieve this. From your page B, whenever you navigate to Page A use the following code:

```
Navigator.pushReplacement(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) => PageA()
  )
);
```

Read all the available navigation options in [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html).